# How to implement parser for the SpecFlow input attributes

Tags: c#, integration-testing, specflow

I have SpecFlow scenario, and I want to specify a range of possible values as an input.

```
Scenario: Search completed successfully 
Given I am on the application screen
    And I enter an number of AA191DD
When I press the search button and wait till search will be completed
Then I should see *AtLeastOne* number of cars available for given number
```

In fact, I am trying to implement some kind of [Times](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Times) struct. 
The requirement is to be able to enter some ranges, like:

- AtLeastOnce
- None
- Exact({number})

The current implementation is: I have Number enum:

```
public enum Number
{
   AtLeastOnce,
   None
}
```

And Specflow bound method takes as Input this enum.

```
public void ThenIShouldSeeNumberOfCarsAvailable(Number numberEnum)
{ 
}
```

But now I do not know how to implement Numbers.Exact(45). 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you are over complicating things a bit but I'll try and give you a working solution as i would do it I think.

First I don't think you can do it with an enum, as you need to store an extra bit of information (the exact number to compare to) so i would probably go with an interface and the implementations. I'd probably call it INumericComparison or similar. Then I'd have an implementation for 'at least', 'none' and 'exactly'. I'd implement an enum like class with static factory methods to create the 3 different types. Then I'd have a StepArgumentTransformation in the steps to convert the text to one of those types. I'm in my phone so the code will be off the cuff, but something like this.

```
Public class NumericComparison
{
    Public static INumericComparison None()
    {
         Return new ExactComparison(0);
    }
    Public static INumericComparison AtLeastOne()
    {
         Return new AtLeastComparison(1);
    }
    Public static INumericComparison Exactly(into value)
    {
         Return new ExactComparison(value);
    }
}

Public interface INumericComparison
{
    Public book PassesComparison(int valueToCompare);
}
```

I'll leave the actual implementations as an exercise for the student.

The step argument transformation can take a regex in specflow so you should be able to come up with some which matches each of your bits of text and just returns one of the static methods